# Beat me to doing?

Tags: expressions

I always hear:

> You beat me to it.

as a fixed expression. However, is it correct to use a verb instead of "it", e.g.:

> You beat me to replying to the email.

?

Comment: The reason you're asking about it is presumably because you haven't encountered ***to beat someone to** [something other than "**it**"]* often, if at all. In the days of the Wild West, *I beat him to **the draw*** would have been common enough, but not today. But there are still plenty of contexts where an "ordinary" noun works (as in *beating someone to **the punchline*** when they're telling a joke). But [*When the cane fell to the floor, he beat me **to picking it up***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+beat+me+to+picking%22), for example, is fine for a verb-based complement.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, yes. In terms of proper usage, not really. It's almost always used in the context of "you beat me to it".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

According to Ngram

[image: ngram]

Cases of "you beat me to it" constitutes more than half of the cases of "you beat me to", but there are still a lot of other cases.
You beat me to the punch
You beat me to her
Tim's older cousins usually beat him to the best parts of the turkey, but this year he got first pick.

See [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beat+me+to)

Comment: There will be some false positives: 'You beat me to a pulp / to death (!?) / to the station / to show how macho you were ...'.

Answer (score 1):

*"You beat me to it."* is a contextual response that implies agreement with an answer previously stated to an open question or query. An example would be: An audience member asks a 4 person panel a question. They receive an answer from panelist #1. Panelist #2 starts out by exclaiming to panelist #1, "You beat me to it." This indicates their general agreement & support for panelist #1's answer.

Other uses could be in a race, or contest, where someone comes in after a friend or competitor. Then, *"You beat me to it."* implies being second to a shared goal.

So, yes. it is okay to include the shared goal in your response.  "You beat me to the answer I was going to give." and, "You beat me to the finish line." are very acceptable alternatives.